# Laravel cannot show foreign in the list

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-7

I am creating a one-one relationship of student and book in laravel. I am unable to show foreign variables in the main page. I would like to show the name of the book in the index page of student. How can I call it in the view?

**Student Table**

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');

         // define foreign key
         $table->foreignId('book_id')
         ->nullable()
         ->constrained()
         ->onUpdate('cascade')
         ->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Book Model**

```
class Book extends Model{


protected $fillable = [
    'name','description' 
 ];
 
 public function students(): HasOne
 {
     return $this->hasOne(Student::class, 'book_id', 'id');
 } }
```

**Student Model**

```
class Student extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'book_id','name' 
 ];


 public function books(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}}
```

**Student Controller**

```
public function index(){
    $students = Student::select('id', 'name')->latest()->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(3);
    $books = Book::all();
    return view('students.index', compact('students', 'books',));
 }
```

**View**

```
@foreach($students as $student)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $student->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student->book_id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
          <td>
               <!-- Edit -->
             <a href="{{ route('students.show',[$student->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show</a>
             <!-- Edit -->
             <a href="{{ route('students.edit',[$student->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</a>
             <!-- Delete -->
             <a href="{{ route('students.delete',$student->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?')">Delete</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You limited the query to select only the id and the name, so the book_id is not returned from the query. Just remove the select (it is useless in pagination cases)

```
public function index(){
    $students = Student::query()->with('books')->latest()->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(3);
    $books = Book::all();
    return view('students.index', compact('students', 'books',));
 }
```

Then in your view you can show the book_id or directly the book name

```
@foreach($students as $student)
       <tr>
          <td>{{ $student->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student->book_id }}, {{ $student->books->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
          <td>
               <!-- Edit -->
             <a href="{{ route('students.show',[$student->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show</a>
             <!-- Edit -->
             <a href="{{ route('students.edit',[$student->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</a>
             <!-- Delete -->
             <a href="{{ route('students.delete',$student->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?')">Delete</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
```